# Reference dimen.xml values from java or xml?

Tags: java, android, xml

I know that `getDimension(R.dimen.value)` returns the value multiplied by a constant depending on the screen density. But what about getting that value from xml (`"@dimen/value"`), it happens the same?

Answer (score 0):

> I know that getDimension(R.dimen.value) returns the value multiplied by a constant depending on the screen density.

That depends on the dimension unit of measure. For most of them, such as `dp`, your statement is correct. `px` does not receive this treatment, so values measured in `px` will be different sizes depending on the screen density.

> But what about getting that value from xml ("@dimen/value"), it happens the same?

Yes, dimension resources behave the same, whether used in Java/Kotlin code or used in resources.

Comment: So there is no point in having a dimen.xml file in every values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-hdpi, etc. folder for diferent screen sizes?

Comment: @Mike087: Correct. If you use `dp`, `sp`, `in`, or `mm` as units of measure, they already take screen density into account. Having different `dimens.xml` files for different screen **sizes** sometimes is useful, such as for having a bit more margin or padding on a tablet than on a phone. Having different `dimens.xml` files for different screen **densities** is unnecessary (and would represent a "code smell").